# How to use a separate assembly DLL for localization resources in Blazor server application (in .NET Core 7)?

Tags: c#, dll, localization, blazor-server-side, globalization

I have a Blazor server application in which I'm trying to add localization support. I want to create a separate assembly DLL to store string resources, my goal is to make this DLL usable across different types of Blazor applications irrespective of what razor component or code it's being used.

Can someone point me an example or guide me to implement this?
All Blazor search results I have looked in have resources files in the same server application. Also, to make sure `IStringLocalization` picks up correct localization string I had to maintain the same folder hierarchy in my resource folder. Which is what I want to avoid so I can use the localized strings efficiently across applications.